# Unable to load dynamic library curl on a very base codeigniter project

Tags: curl, server, codeigniter-3, php-5.6

I have just downloaded the base project of CodeIgniter from the official page, I uploaded it to my server through a Cpanel interface(it's a production server, it also have other pages working on other technologies, it runs php 5.6) and when I open the site on the browser this is what it tells me:

> ### Welcome to Code Igniter!
>
> *The page you are looking at is being generated dynamically by CodeIgniter.*
>
> *If you would like to edit this page you'll find it located at:*
>
> and so on(welcome page)

But the problem comes right below, where it shows:

> #### A PHP Error was encountered
>
> *Severity: Core Warning*
>
> *Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library* >*'/opt/alt/php56/usr/lib64/php/modules/curl.so' -* >*/opt/alt/php56/usr/lib64/php/modules/curl.so: cannot open shared object file:* >*No such file or directory*
>
> *Filename: Unknown*
>
> *Line Number: 0*
>
> *Backtrace:*

I have list the directory: '/opt/alt/php56/usr/lib64/php/modules/' and curl.so isn't there but when I run: get_loaded_extensions() it gives me, among other, curl; so it's like cURL is compiled and loaded, and the most important it is the BASE project, I haven't done anything, I don't want to use cURL, the nearest thing I want to use is DomDocument. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Just type in terminal `sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl` and it should solve the problem.

Comment: sorry for answering so late, thanks for that answer, it was the right, but I didn't have the permissions to do that; I was using someone else server, but thanks any way

Comment: Well, your personal authorization has nothing with correct way of solving the issue. :P